# Is there any way to access native hardware RS-232 ports (ie not USB to RS-232 dongles) in UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

UWP provides the [`Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication) namespace.  However the documentation says that:

> In this release, the namespace supports devices that belong to the USB CDC device class. This includes ports exposed by Serial-to-USB adapters and internal USB to serial bridge chips like those used in Arduino Uno R3s.
>
> System-internal or on-chassis serial ports may be enumerated by DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(), but cannot be opened by SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() because they currently are not supported. However, serial ports connected over USB, such as on USB-to-Serial cables are supported.

Is there any way to get around that limitation and communicate with native COM ports via UWP?

Comment: Check out [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/SerialUART/CS/README.md) scroll down to the `Using the SerialSample App` section.

Comment: @Baddack That appears to be using a USB-RS232 adapter in the middle.  I'm trying to find a way to avoid that.  Unlike consumer PCs industrial/embedded systems still have native hardware ports, and while a USB dongle might only be $10 that adds up to a lot of what looks like 'wasted' money when you're building thousands of systems.  Never mind problems when someone goes to service a device and tries removing the adapter and connecting to the hardware port.

Comment: @Baddack Reading down to the "Let's look at the code" section confirms that it's using `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunications` namespace which only supports USB based adapters on a PC.

Comment: I used the same namespace while writing an app for a RaspberryPi. I was using the hardware ports and not any USB ports. At a PC I think you should just give it a try and just let your app connect to the COM Port. The only thing I noticed that's definitely not working is a virtual COM port. As long as your port has a VID/PID it shoul work.

Comment: @Daniel I don't currently have a PC with a hardware COM port to test (my concern was with future proofing against hardware changes).  As far as it working on your RPi, I know I saw on some piece of MS documentation that I read last week that they had different sets of supported ports for IoT vs PC use.